# How to display the image from ImageField() in Django admin interface?

Tags: django

I want to display a small thumbnail-like image in my Django admin interface. How should I do this? Also it doesn't seem to display any SVG files.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
import datetime
from .validators import validate_file_extension
import base64

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):

    today = date.today()
    t = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day, month, year = today.day, today.month, today.year
    hour, minutes, seconds = t.hour, t.minute, t.second
filename = str(day) + str(month) + str(year) + str(hour) + str(minutes) + str(seconds) + '.png'
    dir = 'media'
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_directory_path, null = True , validators=[validate_file_extension])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a virtual property in your class `Image` and add it as read-only field in the `ImageAdmin`.

Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(
        upload_to = get_directory_path,
        null = True,
        validators=[validate_file_extension]
    )
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @cached_property
    def display_image(self):
        html = '<img src="{img}">'
        if self.image:
            return format_html(html, img=self.image.url)
        return format_html('<strong>There is no image for this entry.<strong>')
    display_image.short_description = 'Display image'
```

The method `display_image` is accessible as a normal property. We check if the field `image` holds a truthy value (i.e. is not null or blank) and return the string containing the `img` tag, otherwise we'll output text showing that there is no image.

Now in your admin class you can do something like this:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('display_image',)
```

Certainly you have to define all other things in the admin, the code above is just an example how to include the virtual property `display_image`.

I hope this helps you and gives you and idea.

EDIT:

You can extend `<img src="{img}">` with further functionalities you need. You can add attributes for `class`, `id`, `alt`, etc. If you want to have fixed size for the image you can create CSS class, for example:

```
.admin-image {
     height: 200px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

and in the Django model adapt the line:

`html = '<img src="{img}" class="admin-image">'`

Comment: For my code, I included only those file formats such as JPG, JPEG, SVG, and PNG. However, when storing SVG as a PNG file, it doesn't seem to be displayed in the Django admin interface but gets stored in the directory. Do you know how to display the image if its in a SVG format?

Comment: Does the admin at least show the short description "Display image"?

Comment: Can you also explain what @cached property does?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) explains `cached_property` in detail.

Comment: I can't make format_html work. It seems unable to find the files, either through .url or .path. It works with web urls though